# GridSearchCV - XGBoost - Early Stopping

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, regression, data-science, xgboost

i am trying to do hyperparemeter search with using scikit-learn's GridSearchCV on XGBoost. During gridsearch i'd like it to early stop, since it reduce search time drastically and (expecting to) have better results on my prediction/regression task. I am using XGBoost via its Scikit-Learn API.

```
    model = xgb.XGBRegressor()
    GridSearchCV(model, paramGrid, verbose=verbose ,fit_params={'early_stopping_rounds':42}, cv=TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=cv).get_n_splits([trainX, trainY]), n_jobs=n_jobs, iid=iid).fit(trainX,trainY)
```

I tried to give early stopping parameters with using fit_params, but then it throws this error which is basically because of lack of validation set which is required for early stopping:

```
/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost/callback.py in callback(env=XGBoostCallbackEnv(model=<xgboost.core.Booster o...teration=4000, rank=0, evaluation_result_list=[]))
    187         else:
    188             assert env.cvfolds is not None
    189 
    190     def callback(env):
    191         """internal function"""
--> 192         score = env.evaluation_result_list[-1][1]
        score = undefined
        env.evaluation_result_list = []
    193         if len(state) == 0:
    194             init(env)
    195         best_score = state['best_score']
    196         best_iteration = state['best_iteration']
```

How can i apply GridSearch on XGBoost with using early_stopping_rounds?

note: model is working without gridsearch, also GridSearch works without 'fit_params={'early_stopping_rounds':42}

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An update to @glao's answer and a response to @Vasim's comment/question, as of sklearn 0.21.3 (note that `fit_params` has been moved out of the instantiation of `GridSearchCV` and been moved into the `fit()` method; also, the import specifically pulls in the sklearn wrapper module from xgboost):

```
import xgboost.sklearn as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit

cv = 2

trainX= [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
trainY = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# these are the evaluation sets
testX = trainX 
testY = trainY

paramGrid = {"subsample" : [0.5, 0.8]}

fit_params={"early_stopping_rounds":42, 
            "eval_metric" : "mae", 
            "eval_set" : [[testX, testY]]}

model = xgb.XGBRegressor()

gridsearch = GridSearchCV(model, paramGrid, verbose=1,             
         cv=TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=cv).get_n_splits([trainX, trainY]))

gridsearch.fit(trainX, trainY, **fit_params)
```

Comment: hi - can this be done using stratifiedkfold as well ?

Comment: @Sandeep: yup, that's actually the default if you choose to simply specify the `cv` parameter in `GridSearchCV` as an integer (indicating how many folds you want to use). i'm afraid I'm not too familiar with the `TimeSeriesSplit` method though, so if you want to use that you should check out the docs.

Comment: thanks for the reply, this solution was what i had been looking for.

Comment: good idea, just one question, xgboost will use a different validation set for each cv to check for early stopping?

Comment: Is it intended that the training and evaluation sets are the same? IE, you set `testX = trainX`.

Comment: @YikeLu, I think I was just being lazy by not making a set of fake other arrays for the test data :) Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @emigre459 no problem, it's more the docs and behavior that are confusing. I have just run with early_stopping_rounds using the xgb.cv method and it does NOT ask for an`eval set` (I'm assuming it just uses the CV folds), and in fact does not require entry of `eval_metric` either, it just uses objective by default.
(Edit/reposted to remove point about return value which I figured out on my own).

Comment: I don't think that this solution works as asked in the OP. It seems to use the same validation set for early stopping, not the CV fold.

Answer (score 23):

When using `early_stopping_rounds` you also have to give `eval_metric` and `eval_set` as input parameter for the fit method. Early stopping is done via calculating the error on an evaluation set. The error has to decrease every `early_stopping_rounds` otherwise the generation of additional trees is stopped early.

See the [documentation](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html) of xgboosts fit method for details.

Here you see a minimal fully working example:

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit

cv = 2

trainX= [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
trainY = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# these are the evaluation sets
testX = trainX 
testY = trainY

paramGrid = {"subsample" : [0.5, 0.8]}

fit_params={"early_stopping_rounds":42, 
            "eval_metric" : "mae", 
            "eval_set" : [[testX, testY]]}

model = xgb.XGBRegressor()
gridsearch = GridSearchCV(model, paramGrid, verbose=1 ,
         fit_params=fit_params,
         cv=TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=cv).get_n_splits([trainX,trainY]))
gridsearch.fit(trainX,trainY)
```

Comment: thanks for reply, it works. but giving pre-defined eval_set is against the nature of the cross validation i guess.

Comment: I guess what you mean is that in real applications you have to make sure eval_set and train set are not overlapping or are the same as here - should have added that. I used the train set just for the sake of simplicity. Early stopping based on the train data does not prevent overfitting.

Comment: @glao: the eval set should be the hold-out set of the cross-validation process to make everything work as intended.

Comment: nowadays "fit_params" is not recommendable because it is going to be deprecated.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelM, and how exactly can we do that? Any help

Comment: @MichaelM  He is right. valid_set should be a hold-out set.

Comment: @ayyayyekokojambo I think you are right. If we perform CV, we do not need a hold-out validation set. I think CV is  designed to optimize traditional train-vaild split method.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that works in a Pipeline with GridSearchCV.  The challenge occurs when you have a pipeline that is required to pre-process your training data. For example, when X is a text document and you need TFTDFVectorizer to vectorize it.

**Over-ride the XGBRegressor or XGBClssifier.fit() Function**

- This step uses train_test_split() to select the specified number of
  validation records from X for the eval_set and then passes the
  remaining records along to fit().
- A new parameter eval_test_size is added to .fit() to control the number of validation records. (see train_test_split [test_size](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) documenation)
- **kwargs passes along any other parameters added by the user for the XGBRegressor.fit() function.

```
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

class XGBRegressor_ES(XGBRegressor):
    
    def fit(self, X, y, *, eval_test_size=None, **kwargs):
        
        if eval_test_size is not None:
        
            params = super(XGBRegressor, self).get_xgb_params()
            
            X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
                X, y, test_size=eval_test_size, random_state=params['random_state'])
            
            eval_set = [(X_test, y_test)]
            
            # Could add (X_train, y_train) to eval_set 
            # to get .eval_results() for both train and test
            #eval_set = [(X_train, y_train),(X_test, y_test)] 
            
            kwargs['eval_set'] = eval_set
            
        return super(XGBRegressor_ES, self).fit(X_train, y_train, **kwargs)
```

**Example Usage**

Below is a multistep pipeline that includes multiple transformations to X. The pipeline's fit() function passes the new evaluation parameter to the XGBRegressor_ES class above as xgbr__eval_test_size=200.  In this example:

- X_train contains text documents passed to the pipeline.
- XGBRegressor_ES.fit() uses train_test_split() to select 200 records from X_train for the validation set and early stopping. (This could also be a percentage such as xgbr__eval_test_size=0.2)
- The remaining records in X_train are passed along to XGBRegressor.fit() for the actual fit().
- Early stopping may now occur after 75 rounds of unchanged boosting for each cv fold in a gridsearch.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectPercentile, f_regression
   
xgbr_pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer()),
                     ('vt',VarianceThreshold()),
                     ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
                     ('Sp', SelectPercentile()),
                     ('xgbr',XGBRegressor_ES(n_estimators=2000,
                                             objective='reg:squarederror',
                                             eval_metric='mae',
                                             learning_rate=0.0001,
                                             random_state=7))    ])

X_train = train_idxs['f_text'].values
y_train = train_idxs['Pct_Change_20'].values
```

**Example Fitting the Pipeline:**

```
%time xgbr_pipe.fit(X_train, y_train, 
                    xgbr__eval_test_size=200,
                    xgbr__eval_metric='mae', 
                    xgbr__early_stopping_rounds=75)
```

**Example Fitting GridSearchCV:**

```
learning_rate = [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
param_grid = dict(xgbr__learning_rate=learning_rate)

grid_search = GridSearchCV(xgbr_pipe, param_grid, scoring="neg_mean_absolute_error", n_jobs=-1, cv=10)
grid_result = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train, 
                    xgbr__eval_test_size=200,
                    xgbr__eval_metric='mae', 
                    xgbr__early_stopping_rounds=75)
```