# cross_val_score for xgboost with "early_stopping_rounds" returns "IndexError"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, xgboost

I am working on a regression model in python (v3.6) using sklearn and xgboost.
I want to calculate sklearn.cross_val_score with early_stopping_rounds. The following code returns an error:

```
xgb_model = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=600,
                             learning_rate=0.06)

xgb_cv = cross_val_score(xgb_model, train_x, train_y, 
                         cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error',
                         fit_params={'early_stopping_rounds':3})

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Also, if I try to pass the parameter as 'xgbregressor__early_stopping_rounds' (as found online in some related topics), the following error shows up:

```
TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument
'xgbregressor__early_stopping_rounds'
```

If I run the same model without "fit_params", everything works fine.
Is there any way I can avoid this error while using cross_val_score?

Comment: I think you can find the solution in this stackoverflow response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43014158/6413835

Comment: You are right, thanks!

Comment: xgboost has its own cross validation function. `xgboost.cv`. link: http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html . Is there a reason not using that?

Comment: Initially, I tried it with `xgboost.cv` following this post [https://jessesw.com/XG-Boost/](https://jessesw.com/XG-Boost/), but then switched back to the sklearn framework. I just feel more comfortable with it. Do you see any actual advantage from using `xgboost.cv`?

Comment: Just that its more compatible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it with glao's answer from here [GridSearchCV - XGBoost - Early Stopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993550/gridsearchcv-xgboost-early-stopping/43014158#43014158), as suggested by lbcommer - thanks!

To avoid overfitting, I evaluated the algorithm using a separate part of the training data as validation dataset. See my code below:

```
train_x, val_x, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(train_x, train_y, test_size = 0.30, random_state=1)

xgb_model = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=600, learning_rate=0.06)

fit_params={'early_stopping_rounds': 30, 
            'eval_metric': 'mae',
            'verbose': False,
            'eval_set': [[val_x, val_y]]}

xgb_cv = cross_val_score(xgb_model, train_x, train_y, 
                         cv = 5, 
                         scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error',
                         fit_params = fit_params)
```

Comment: Obviously it should not be necessary to have a hold-out when doing K-fold CV. The eval_set should just be the test split for each k-fold. Ultimately I had to do this with xgb.train in a simple for loop.