# RandomizedSearchCV & XGBoost + with Early Stopping

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am trying to use 'AUCPR' as evaluation criteria for early-stopping using Sklearn's RandomSearchCV & Xgboost but I am unable to specify `maximize=True` for early stopping fit params. Instead the eval_metric minimizes for AUCPR.

I have already referred to this question:
[GridSearchCV - XGBoost - Early Stopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42993550/gridsearchcv-xgboost-early-stopping)

But it seems the early stopping works only for minimization objectives? The best iteration in early stopping is considered when AUCPR is the lowest which is not the correct optimization.

```
    xgb = XGBClassifier()


    params = {
    'min_child_weight': [0.1, 1, 5, 10, 50],
    'gamma': [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 5],
    'subsample': [0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
    'colsample_bytree': [0.6, 0.8, 1.0],
    'max_depth': [5, 10, 25, 50],
    'learning_rate': [0.0001, 0.001, 0.1, 1],
    'n_estimators': [50, 100, 250, 500],
    'reg_alpha': [0.0001, 0.001, 0.1, 1],
    'reg_lambda': [0.0001, 0.001, 0.1, 1]
    }

    fit_params={"early_stopping_rounds":5,
                "eval_metric" : "aucpr", 
                "eval_set" : [[X_val, y_val]]
               }

        random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(xgb, 
                                           cv=folds,
                                           param_distributions=params, 
                                           n_iter=param_comb, 
                                           scoring=make_scorer(auc_precision_recall_curve, needs_proba=True), 
                                           n_jobs=10,
                                           verbose=10, 
                                           random_state=1001,
                                          )

random_search.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems AUCPR maximize does not work for sklearn

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/3712

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29025668)

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo I disagree in this instance. Even if you remove the link, it still contains valuable information (the fact that AUCPR maximize doesn't work for sklearn). I don't know if it's a *correct* answer or not, but it is an answer.